# Emission of a "set of discrete frequencies" vs "continuous" emission?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, spectroscopy, discrete, photonics

I am reading some notes for a class on computer graphics, and in a section introducing concepts such as the pinhole camera model, the author says that "light sources can emit light either as a set of discrete frequencies or continuously". I have no idea what the author means here in trying to distinguish between the emission of a "set of discrete frequencies" and "continuous" emission. Does anyone understands what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some experience with spectroscopy you can find some sources that emit exactly one frequency, for example a [sodium lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp) emits monocromatic light with a wavelength of 589 nanometer, or a hydrogen lamp would emit exactly at the colors of the [Balmer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series).
Other sources emits a continuum spectrum of frequency: each frequency has a different intensity. A model in which we see a continuum spectrum is the [blackbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)

Comment: Obviously, monochromatic light is impossible; but a spectrum of 589.0 nm and 589.56 nm is as close as I've ever seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp#Development

Comment: It's not clear to me which of what you describe is the "set of discrete frequencies", and which is the "continuous" emissions. You seem to have clumped the hydrogen lamp with the "monochromatic", sodium lamp source; but, as you said, the hydrogen lamp emits the colours of the Balmer series, so it's not even close to being monochromatic, and seems to actually *contrast* with the sodium lamp example. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, rereading my last comment I see it's not very clear. The hydrogen lamp emit the colours of the balmer series: those are exactly a fixed series of colours (at 656, 486, 434 and 410 nanometers). Those are puntuals: you won't see any wavelength, so it emits on a set of discrete frequency. The sodium light is also discrete: it emits exactly at 589 nanometers, which is like the hydrogen lamp but with only one wavelength. On the other side there is, for example, the blackbody, which emits on a continuous spectrum

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.